# Reference request for a proof : every convex open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, reference-request, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Is there a reference of a proof of the following statement?

If $U$ is a nonempty convex open subset of $\Bbb R^n$, then $U$ is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: The answer is positive even for a star shape. See [MO article](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4468/what-are-the-open-subsets-of-mathbbrn-that-are-diffeomorphic-to-mathbb/4516#4516).

Comment: It was asked in MSE at least three times before, and answered as well.

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1869739/why-are-geodesically-convex-sets-diffeomorphic-to-bbb-rn/1869934, I am sure, there are more.